# Converting Tex string in Tex number

Tags: string, numbers, latex, tex

I have problem using automatically generated Tex string in arguments where a numeric value are required (e.g. in ifthenelse comparison). Here is a sample minimal code :

```
\newcommand\testC{123}
\ifthenelse{\testC<0}{negative}{positive} % works fine !

\newcommand{\testD}{\luaexec{tex.write("123")}} % write to avoid the print carriage return - produces also 123 as \testC
\testD % prompt 132 just as \testC "apparently"
\ifthenelse{\testD<0}{negative}{positive} % error "! Missing number, treated as zero"

\newcounter{compteur}
\setcounter{compteur}{\testD} % error "! Missing number, treated as zero"
\ifthenelse{\thecompteur<0}{negative}{positive}
```

I can't find a way to convert from a string to a number accepted for arithmetic comparison (and other operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\luaexec` (requires `\usepackage{luacode}`) is not expandable, so it cannot be used in places where (Lua)TeX expects a `<number>` after expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\testC{123}
\ifthenelse{\testC<0}{negative}{positive} % works fine !

\newcommand{\testD}{\directlua{tex.sprint("123")}} % write to avoid the print carriage return - p$

\testD % prompt 132 just as \testC "apparently"

\ifthenelse{\testD<0}{negative}{positive} % error "! Missing number, treated as zero"

\newcounter{compteur}
\setcounter{compteur}{\testD} % error "! Missing number, treated as zero"
\ifthenelse{\value{compteur}<0}{negative}{positive}

\end{document}
```

It's better using `\value{compteur}` in tests.